# download multiple files on new tabs using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am tasked to download the first 25 books from https://www.gutenberg.org/ but I need to download everything at once. Here's what I have so far.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        var link = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/"+i+".epub.images";
        window.open(link, "_blank");
};

// https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/150.epub.images --> sample link
```

The approach that I'm looking at is to open multiple new tabs and wait for each one to download the epub file. However, this only downloads the first book and doesn't continue to the next one.

I already researched on how to open multiple new tabs and on how to download multiple items at once but nothing works. I'm afraid they're already depreciated since those answers was 5+ years ago.

Comment: That is because broswer have freezing feature

Comment: Would you mind linking to the answers you looked through? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery.

Comment: maybe you can try to use `fetch`/`xhr`/`jquery ajax` to download the epubs, then archive it with js and download the archive